# Multiple Git Tags Appear In Software Release on GitHub

Tags: git, github, tags, migration, clearcase

I'm currently attempting to migrate a large amount of software releases to GitHub from a legacy system (ClearCase).  While doing so, I've created this workflow:

1. Read label from ClearCase
2. Generate and apply config spec via label
3. Robocopy files/directories from ClearCase to pre-cloned/initialized git repository
4. Stage all files to be added in Git
5. Create a commit
6. Tag this commit
7. Push commit and tags to GitHub

After pushing some tags to GitHub, I navigated to My Repository -> Releases, and looked at one of the most recent tags pushed.  To my surprise, not only was the tag that I expected to be present there, but also a number of other previous tags from commits earlier in the master branch (all of the releases are being added to the master branch in order.)

Why is there a plethora of tags being applied to the same release?  Am I reading the release wrong?  I've included a screenshot of an example of how I'm seeing the multiple tags:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would see the same in any file part of a commit referenced by multiple tags.

The goal is to list all the tags referencing that commit.
You can then see:

- when said commit was first tagged
- its most recent tag.

Consider for instance [`git/git` commit 799767c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/799767cc98b2f8e6f82d0de4bef9b5e8fcc16e97):

[image: Most recent and oldest tag referencing that commit]

Click on the '...' part and:

[image: A lot of intermediate tags]

Comment: Thank you so much!  I was really scared that it meant that all my tags were pointing at the same level of content